# How to implement delete with foldr in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I've been studying folds for the past few days. I can implement simple functions with them, like `length`, `concat` and `filter`. What I'm stuck at is trying to implement with `foldr` functions like `delete`, `take` and `find`. I have implemented these with explicit recursion but it doesn't seem obvious to me how to convert these types of functions to right folds.

I have studied the tutorials by Graham Hutton and Bernie Pope. Imitating Hutton's `dropWhile`, I was able to implement `delete` with `foldr` but it fails on infinite lists.

From reading [Implement insert in haskell with foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568276/implement-insert-in-haskell-with-foldr), [How can this function be written using foldr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057028/how-can-this-function-be-written-using-foldr) and [Implementing take using foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879940/implementing-take-using-foldr), it would seem that I need to use `foldr` to generate a function which then does something. But I don't really understand these solutions and don't have an idea how to implement for example `delete` this way.

Could you explain to me a general strategy for implementing with `foldr` lazy versions of functions like the ones I mentioned. Maybe you could also implement `delete` as an example since this probably is one of the easiest.

I'm looking for a detailed explanation that a beginner can understand. I'm not interested in just solutions, I want to develop an understanding so I can come up with solutions to similar problems myself.

Thanks.

**Edit:** At the moment of writing there is one useful answer but it's not quite what I was looking for. I'm more interested in an approach that uses foldr to generate a function, which then does something. The links in my question have examples of this. I don't quite understand those solutions so I would like to have more information on this approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`delete` is a modal search. It has two different modes of operation - whether it's already found the result or not.  You can use `foldr` to construct a function that passes the state down the line as each element is checked. So in the case of `delete`, the state can be a simple `Bool`. It's not exactly the best type, but it will do.

Once you have identified the state type, you can start working on the `foldr` construction. I'm going to walk through figuring it out the way I did. I'll be enabling `ScopedTypeVariables` just so I can annotate the type of subexpressions better. One you know the state type, you know you want `foldr` to generate a function taking a value of that type, and returning a value of the desired final type. That's enough to start sketching things.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

delete :: forall a. Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete a xs = foldr f undefined xs undefined
  where
    f :: a -> (Bool -> [a]) -> (Bool -> [a])
    f x g = undefined
```

It's a start. The exact meaning of `g` is a little bit tricky here.  It's actually the function for processing the rest of the list. It's accurate to look at it as a continuation, in fact. It absolutely represents performing the rest of the folding, with your whatever state you choose to pass along. Given that, it's time to figure out what to put in some of those `undefined` places.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

delete :: forall a. Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete a xs = foldr f undefined xs undefined
  where
    f :: a -> (Bool -> [a]) -> (Bool -> [a])
    f x g found | x == a && not found = g True
                | otherwise           = x : g found
```

That seems relatively straightforward.  If the current element is the one being searched for, and it hasn't yet been found, don't output it, and continue with the state set to `True`, indicating it's been found.  `otherwise`, output the current value and continue with the current state.  This just leaves the rest of the arguments to `foldr`. The last one is the initial state.  The other one is the state function for an empty list.  Ok, those aren't too bad either.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

delete :: forall a. Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete a xs = foldr f (const []) xs False
  where
    f :: a -> (Bool -> [a]) -> (Bool -> [a])
    f x g found | x == a && not found = g True
                | otherwise           = x : g found
```

No matter what the state is, produce an empty list when an empty list is encountered. And the initial state is that the element being searched for has not yet been found.

This technique is also applicable in other cases.  For instance, `foldl` can be written as a `foldr` this way. If you look at `foldl` as a function that repeatedly transforms an initial accumulator, you can guess that's the function being produced - how to transform the initial value.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foldl :: forall a b. (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f z xs = foldr g id xs z
  where
    g :: b -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
    g x cont acc = undefined
```

The base cases aren't too tricky to find when the problem is defined as manipulating the initial accumulator, named `z` there. The empty list is the identity transformation, `id`, and the value passed to the created function is `z`.

The implementation of `g` is trickier. It can't just be done blindly on types, because there are two different implementations that use all the expected values and type-check. This is a case where types aren't enough, and you need to consider the meanings of the functions available.

Let's start with an inventory of the values that seem like they should be used, and their types.  The things that seem like they must need to be used in the body of `g` are `f :: a -> b -> a`, `x :: b`, `cont :: (a -> a)`, and `acc :: a`. `f` will obviously take `x` as its second argument, but there's a question of the appropriate place to use `cont`. To figure out where it goes, remember that it represents the transformation function returned by processing the rest of the list, and that `foldl` processes the current element and then passes the result of that processing to the rest of the list.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foldl :: forall a b. (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f z xs = foldr g id xs z
  where
    g :: b -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
    g x cont acc = cont $ f acc x
```

This also suggests that `foldl'` can be written this way with only one tiny change:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

foldl' :: forall a b. (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl' f z xs = foldr g id xs z
  where
    g :: b -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
    g x cont acc = cont $! f acc x
```

The difference is that `($!)` is used to suggest evaluation of `f acc x` before it's passed to `cont`. (I say "suggest" because there are some edge cases where `($!)` doesn't force evaluation even as far as WHNF.)

Answer (score 7):

`delete` doesn't operate on the entire list evenly.  The structure of the computation isn't just considering the whole list one element at a time.  It differs after it hits the element it's looking for.  This tells you it can't be implemented as *just* a `foldr`. There will have to be some sort of post-processing involved.

When that happens, the general pattern is that you build a pair of values and just take one of them at completion of the `foldr`.  That's probably what you did when you imitated Hutton's `dropWhile`, though I'm not sure since you didn't include code.  Something like this?

```
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete a = snd . foldr (\x (xs1, xs2) -> if x == a then (x:xs1, xs1) else (x:xs1, x:xs2)) ([], [])
```

The main idea is that `xs1` is always going to be the full tail of the list, and `xs2` is the result of the `delete` over the tail of the list. Since you only want to remove the first element that matches, you don't want to use the result of `delete` over the tail when you do match the value you're searching for, you just want to return the rest of the list unchanged - which fortunately is what's always going to be in `xs1`.

And yeah, that doesn't work on infinite lists - but only for one very specific reason.  The lambda is too strict.  `foldr` only works on infinite lists when the function it is provided doesn't always force evaluation of its second argument, and that lambda does always force evaluation of its second argument in the pattern match on the pair. Switching to an irrefutable pattern match fixes that, by allowing the lambda to produce a constructor before ever examining its second argument.

```
delete :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete a = snd . foldr (\x ~(xs1, xs2) -> if x == a then (x:xs1, xs1) else (x:xs1, x:xs2)) ([], [])
```

That's not the only way to get that result. Using a let-binding or `fst` and `snd` as accessors on the tuple would also do the job. But it is the change with the smallest diff.

The most important takeaway here is to be very careful with handling the second argument to the reducing function you pass to `foldr`. You want to defer examining the second argument whenever possible, so that the `foldr` can stream lazily in as many cases as possible.

If you look at that lambda, you see that the branch taken is chosen before doing anything with the second argument to the reducing function. Furthermore, you'll see that most of the time, the reducing function produces a list constructor in both halves of the result tuple before it ever needs to evaluate the second argument. Since those list constructors are what make it out of `delete`, they are what matter for streaming - so long as you don't let the pair get in the way. And making the pattern-match on the pair irrefutable is what keeps it out of the way.

As a bonus example of the streaming properties of `foldr`, consider my favorite example:

```
dropWhileEnd :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
dropWhileEnd p = foldr (\x xs -> if p x && null xs then [] else x:xs) []
```

It streams - as much as it can. If you figure out exactly when and why it does and doesn't stream, you'll understand pretty much every detail of the streaming structure of `foldr`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and find it useful. I would upvote if I had enough reputation, but I don't accept yet because your answer is not quite what I'm looking for. But that's my fault for not making the question more precise, I'll see if I can edit. I'm more interested in an approach that uses foldr to generate a function. You're right that your first implementation is pretty much what I tried.

Comment: @user168064 Ok.  After spending ~3 hours learning the topic, I can answer your intended question, too.  I think it deserves to be a second answer more than an edit to this one, so another answer's incoming.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple delete, implemented with foldr:

```
delete :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete a xs = foldr (\x xs -> if x == a then (xs) else (x:xs)) [] xs
```

Comment: This isn't delete though. Delete only removes the first occurrence. That's where the "challenge" is.