# Haskell: Folding over trees

Tags: haskell

I am going through some old courses online and came across this task:

```
data Tree a = Leaf 
            | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
            deriving (Show, Eq)

fold :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
fold _ acc Leaf           = acc
fold f acc (Branch v l r) = f v (fold f acc l) (fold f acc r)

foldRT :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldRT _ acc Leaf = acc
foldRT f acc (Branch v l r) = foldRT f (f v (foldRT f acc r)) l
```

The task is to rewrite `foldRT` in terms of `fold`. I have been stuck on it for ages and can't wrap my head around it.

A walk through would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @pdoherty926 I believe there isn't more to it -- a reconstructed problem statement might be "implement the list-like/`Foldable`-like fold (`foldRT`) in terms of the catamorphism/general fold (`fold`)".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458645/383200 for a discussion of the general technique.  That answer goes over it for lists, but the same idea applies.

Answer (score 1):

As its name and type signature suggest, `foldRT` is a bona fide right fold for your tree (you can convince yourself of that by hand-evaluating it for something like `Branch 1 (Branch 0 Leaf Leaf) (Branch 2 Leaf Leaf)`). That means implementing `Foldable` will give you `foldRT`: `foldRT = foldr`. Why is that relevant? Because, in this case, it is much easier to implement `foldMap` than it is to figure out how to write `foldr` directly:

```
-- Note that l and r here aren't the subtrees, but the results of folding them.
instance Foldable Tree where
    foldMap f = fold (\v l r -> l <> f v <> r) mempty
```

If you want to write `foldRT` without relying on a `Foldable` instance, all you need is expanding the `foldMap`-based definition of `foldr` (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23319683/2751851) for the details I'll gloss over here):

```
foldRT f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z

-- To make things less clumsy, let's use:
foldEndo f = appEndo . foldMap (Endo . f)
-- foldEndo f = flip (foldRT f)

foldEndo f = appEndo . fold (\v l r -> l <> Endo (f v) <> r) mempty

-- As we aren't mentioning foldMap anymore, we can drop the Endo wrappers.
-- mempty @(Endo _) = Endo id
-- Endo g <> Endo f = Endo (g . f)
foldEndo f = fold (\v l r -> l . f v . r) id

-- Bringing it all back home:
foldRT :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldRT f z t = fold (\v l r -> l . f v . r) id t z
```

(Note that we ultimately reached a solution of the sort [suggested by Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458645/2751851), only through an indirect route.)